# #XVAL shows data index (integer) instead of string of an array

Tags: vb.net, charts

I want to know why #XVAL shows the index (from 0 to 3 since there is 4 items in there) instead of ex:"< .50%" and so on. This will help me to change the desired output, which is "< .50%".

I've tried #AXISLABEL too and it doesn't work.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
Private Sub LoadGraphicChart()
    Try

        C1Chart2.ChartGroups(0).ChartData.SeriesList.Clear()
        ' Data 
        Dim items As String() = New String() {"< 0.50%", "0.50% - 1.00%", "1.00% - 2.00%", "> 2.00%"}
        Dim unitHData As Double() = New Double() {7 / 100, 0, 0, 1 / 100}
        'first try, populating the series
        Dim unitH As C1.Win.C1Chart.ChartDataSeriesCollection = C1Chart2.ChartGroups(0).ChartData.SeriesList
        'unitH.Clear()
        Dim series As ChartDataSeries = unitH.AddNewSeries
        series.Label = "Unit Holder"
        series.LineStyle.Color = Color.MediumPurple
        series.X.CopyDataIn(items)
        series.Y.CopyDataIn(unitHData)
        'tooltip
        C1Chart2.ToolTip.Enabled = True

        For Each ds As ChartDataSeries In unitH
            ds.TooltipText = "Series = {#TEXT}" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "X = {#XVAL}" + ControlChars.Cr + ControlChars.Lf + "Y = {#YVAL:0.00%}"
        Next ds
    End Try
End Sub
```

This is what the tooltip currently looks like:

[image: Image Example]

Comment: Everything looks fine. What is your problem? I don't understand your question. `items[0] = "< 0.50%"` contains 7/100

Comment: @cSteusloff oh sorry, my question is, how to change the output of #XVAL from (0) to ("< 0.50%) in the tooltiptext

Answer (score 1):

Changing from using tooltiptext to CoordToDataIndex solved my problems.
Here is how I use it:

```
Private Sub C1Chart2_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles C1Chart2.MouseClick
    Dim SeriesOutput As Integer
    Dim PointOutput As Integer
    Dim DistanceOutput As Integer
    Dim items As String() = New String() {InputLabel10.Text, InputLabel9.Text, InputLabel8.Text, InputLabel7.Text}
    Dim unitHData As String() = New String() {FormatPercent((CDbl(lblPersen00.Text) / 100)), FormatPercent((CDbl(lblPersen05.Text) / 100)), FormatPercent((CDbl(lblPersen10.Text) / 100)), FormatPercent((CDbl(lblPersen20.Text) / 100))}

    C1Chart2.ChartGroups.Group0.CoordToDataIndex(e.X, e.Y, CoordinateFocusEnum.XandYCoord, SeriesOutput, PointOutput, DistanceOutput)

    Debug.WriteLine("Series Index : " & SeriesOutput.ToString())
    Debug.WriteLine("Point Index : " & PointOutput.ToString())
    Debug.WriteLine("Distance from Point: " & DistanceOutput.ToString())

    'MessageBox.Show(PointOutput)
    If PointOutput.ToString <> "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("X : " & items(PointOutput) & ControlChars.Cr & ControlChars.Lf & "Y : " & unitHData(PointOutput))
    End If

End Sub
```

Result(First Data): [image: First Data]

Result(Last Data): [image: Last Data]